# React refetches images after sort

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-redux, react-hooks

There is a component that renders some articles on the page with an option to sort from newest to oldest.

In the file there is a function that returns the view for these articles and it is used in the return statement.

```
const RenderBookmarks = () => {
    return bookmarkArticles?.length > 0 ?
      <ArticleSection articles={bookmarkArticles}/> :
      <Text textAlign="center">{MESSAGES.NO_ARTICLES}</Text>;
};
.
.
.
return (
    <>
      {status === "loading"
        ? <ArticleSectionSkeleton/>
        : <RenderBookmarks/>}
    </>);
```

**The problem** is whenever the sort is applied react refetch the images from their respective URLs.

**But on the other hand**, if the articles are rendered via a variable. Call to image URLs are not made on sort.

```
  articles = bookmarkArticles?.length > 0 ?
      <ArticleSection articles={bookmarkArticles}/> :
      <Text textAlign="center">{MESSAGES.NO_ARTICLES}</Text>;
.
.
.

 return (
    <>
      {status === "loading"
        ? <ArticleSectionSkeleton/>
        : articles}
    </>);
```

I am not able to understand why React is refetching images if they are rendered via a function. Can some explain this behavior?

Here is a gif with `<RenderBookmarks/>`
[image]

and with `articles` variable
[image]

Answer (score 1):

The example with the component refetches because all components are re-rendered after a page refresh.
On the other hand when you use a variable to render articles it stores `articles` in the computers memory and doesn't to re-render them.

Comment: On sorting the state is updating. Shouldn't react update the `articles` variable ?

Answer (score 1):

I think it has to do with the function `RenderBookmarks` being a different identity on every render compared to the variable case where `ArticleSection` is the same identity since it's from outside the component.

HTML will refetch an image if the actual `img` HTML element is removed from the DOM tree and then put back. But the real DOM will only be touched if the virtual DOM is not identical from my undertstanding. I would think however, that your function `RenderBookmarks` would produce the same virtual DOM as variable case and thus not tear down any existing `img`. So I'm unsure.

I replicated this and I see in Chrome Inspector that my `div` containing `img`s in the `RenderBookmarks` case is destroyed. GIF shows this since `div` is deselected in Inspector (upper part). The corresponding `div` in the variable case is not destroyed causing no delete and recreate of DOM node (lower part).

[GIF showing function approach removed HTML DOM nodes](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Qtj4L.gif)

[Source code of replication](https://github.com/PelicanQ/img-refetch-answer)